# Code need to be repeated in php

Tags: php, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="big">
    <div class="small">
        <img src="images/icons/AC.png" />
        AC &amp; Refrigeration
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <img src="images/icons/AC.png" />
        AC &amp; Refrigeration
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is such that the class='big' has to be repeated to show the icons enclosed in the class='small'.

the class-'small' is to display only 2 icons inside the div for class='big' once the two icons in the class='small' has displayed two icons, the div big has to be repeated. the same shall continue for about 80 icons.

please suggest how i can use a counter variable (e.g. one that begins with 1, increments to 2 and then resets to 1). Use the counter value to wrap two folder items (i.e. div class="small" ../div) within the div class="big"../div.

Comment: What do you have so far, in terms of PHP code?

Comment: I am using CouchCMS and i have code that is required only for couch. No PHP code as of yet. this is a plain and simple html code.

Comment: Actually i dont know how to usea loop. I am a front end designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided an even number of icons, something like this would work:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    foreach( $icons as $icon ) {
        if ( $counter % 2 == 0 ) echo '<div class="big">';
?>
    <div class="small">
        <img src="<?= $icon->src ?>" />
        <?= $icon->name ?>
    </div>
<?php
        if ( $counter % 2 == 1 ) echo '</div>';
        $counter++;
    }
?>
```

You'd have to add a little extra code to account for odd cases in necessary.  The trick is to keep track of when you are on an even or odd icon with `$counter % 2`